# QT4 > QT5 for QDesktopServices::storageLocation

Tags: qt

I am trying to convert the following code to a QT5 version:

```
QString getSaveFileName(QWidget *parent, const QString &caption,
                                 const QString &dir,
                                 const QString &filter,
                                 QString *selectedSuffixOut)
{
    QString selectedFilter;
    QString myDir;
    if(dir.isEmpty()) // Default to user documents location
    {
        myDir = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DocumentsLocation);
    }
    else
```

But sadly I am getting the following error:

```
error: no member named 'storageLocation' in 'QDesktopServices'
        myDir = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DocumentsLocation);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

and

```
error: no member named 'DocumentsLocation' in 'QDesktopServices'
        myDir = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DocumentsLocation);
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: Have you tried [googling](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=fO1wWtC1HoGujQPn1ruIBA&q=storageLocation+QDesktopServices+qt5&oq=storageLocation+QDesktopServices+qt5&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1.92652.98067.0.98244.11.11.0.0.0.0.379.1088.0j3j1j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.3.667....0.weaDAFEanEE)? (Third link down looks promising: see [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/22448/solved-qdesktopservices-storagelocation-substituion-in-qt-5))

Answer (score 2):

Since Qt 5, `storageLocation()` and `displayName()` methods of `QDesktopServices` are replaced by functionality provided by the `QStandardPaths` class, so your `myDir` can be assigned like this:

```
myDir = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
```

Comment: See also (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices-obsolete.html#storageLocation) for more migration tips from QDesktopServices